# Tagging sentences with custom defined dictionary

Tags: python, nltk, tagging, sequencematcher

I am trying to tag sentences using a custom defined dictionary.
For example if I have two text files (1. My sentences, 2. My dictionary)

**Sentences file:**

I have abdominal pain and have difficulty breathing

**Dictionary file:**

Abdominal pain, difficulty breathing

*I would like output to be like this:*

**New file:**

I have abdominal pain (AE) and have difficulty breathing (AE)

How can this be done?
Please see the following code:

```
import csv
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as SM
from nltk.util import ngrams

import codecs

with open('dictionary.csv','r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    myfile = open("sentences.txt", "rt")
    my3file = open("tagged_sentences.txt", "w")
    hay = myfile.read()
    myfile.close()

phrases = []
for row in reader:
    needle = row[1]
    needle_length = len(needle.split())
    max_sim_val = 0.9
    max_sim_string = u""
    for ngram in ngrams(hay.split(), needle_length + int(.2 * needle_length)):
        hay_ngram = u" ".join(ngram)

        similarity = SM(None, hay_ngram, needle).ratio()
        if similarity > max_sim_val:
            max_sim_val = similarity
            max_sim_string = hay_ngram
            str = [row[1] , ' ', max_sim_val.__str__(),' ', max_sim_string , '\n']
            str1 = max_sim_string , row[2]
            phrases.append((max_sim_string, row[2]))

for line in hay.splitlines():
    if any(max_sim_string in line for max_sim_string, _ in phrases):
        for phrase in phrases:
            max_sim_string, _ = phrase
            if max_sim_string in line:
                tag_sent = line.replace(max_sim_string, phrase.__str__())
                my3file.writelines(tag_sent + '\n')
                print(tag_sent)
                break        
    else:
        my3file.writelines(line + '\n')

csvFile.close()
```

The above code just creates an empty "tagged_sentences" file
Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far? post the code and the problems you have faced! and i recommend you read this before posting questions in SO community. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). let us reproduce the problem, so read this also. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please see edit thanks

Comment: First you need to clean you file management. `with open()` structure doesn't need closing a file since it is done when you go out of the stucture (this is why you got the error since the file is closed). And you mix it with file openning directly in this structure which is in my opinion not a good idea.